# O que significa o erro "Design has only one primary sampling unit"?

Tags: r

Estou utilizando o pacote Survey do R e, ao realizar alguns `svymean()`, o que retorna é o *warning*:

> Design has only one primary sampling unit.

Comment: Henrique, fica masi fácil de responder se você mandar um exemplo de código em que isso acontece. Não estou conseguindo reproduzir o seu erro.

Comment: Tem pouca info msm, mas chuto que o problema deve estar em algum calculo que demande graus de liberdade, como variância. O resultado envolve variância? Pq se sim, deve ter algum particionamento que ta isolando uma única observação, fazendo o cálculo da variância ficar indefinido. Uma tentativa seria considerar menos variáveis de controle (chutando q elas existem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem código fica difícil te ajudar, mas esse erro está geralmente associado ao calculo da variância (que precisa, obviamente, de mais de uma observação). É possível contornar isso alterando a opção de ação para 'lonely PSU' através do `options(survey.lonely.psu = )`, que aceita as opções:

> Handling of strata with a single PSU that are not certainty PSUs  is
>   controlled by ‘options("survey.lonely.psu")’. The default  setting is
>   ‘"fail"’, which gives an error. Use ‘"remove"’ to  ignore that PSU for
>   variance computation, ‘"adjust"’ to center the  stratum at the
>   population mean rather than the stratum mean, and  ‘"average"’ to
>   replace the variance contribution of the stratum by  the average
>   variance contribution across strata. As of version
>    3.4-2 ‘as.svrepdesign’ also uses this option.

Answer (score 1):

Isso provavelmente significa que você declarou o seu desenho amostral como tendo conglomerados quando na realidade ele não possui. Se for esse o caso, quando você declarar o desenho amostral na função `svydesign()`, utilize o valor '1' para o parâmetro *id*. Por exemplo:

```
design <- svydesign(id =~ 1, strata =~ estrato, weights =~ pesos, data = dados)
```

Outra possibilidade é que sua variável de conglomerização (o parâmetro id na função svdesign) possua um único valor. Nesse caso, se você realmente tiver conglomerização no seu plano amostral, você indicar nessa variável a qual conglomerado cada elemento no seu conjunto de dados pertence.

De qualquer forma, manda o código , como o Daniel e o Athos sugeriram, para podermos diagnosticar isso melhor.